# is there a 'fixed header' or 'sticky header' for react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo

Is there a way to have fixed and permeant top-titlebar(I think it's called as Header?) for react native?

Almost like a status bar, it's always there. But it needs to be at the top (even before the 'header' from the react-navigation)

My plan was to put a global-search input there, so anywhere in the app you can search(Search content not affected by the screen that's presented at the moment. Pure global search always available.)

Is there a way to do this? I'm currently working with expo and react-navigation.

--- Edit

I add the screenshot of wireframe that shows what I meant. You'll notice that the Search bar stays at the top regardless the screen you are on. It's a global search bar.

-- Edit

I think I need to say this clearly. I'm trying to do this with **ReactNavigation**. I think I need to play with 'createAppContainer', or any create navigator function like 'createDrawerNavigator' and figure out a way to put in the fixed header with the navigate-able screens.

[image: Example Navigation with Searchbar]

Comment: You want to put a search bar above the navigation header bar? Do you have any example of this?!

Comment: Yup. I'll draw it out and update my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way myself. =)

So the key was to introduce the custom navigator.

Custom Navigator can extend my existing Tab Navigator, and the render part can return almost whatever I want PLUS the regular view that my TabNavigator will have.

My app has Drawer and Tab Navigator. So in my case Drawer Navigator has bunch of routes and one of the routes is the Custom Navigator that's extending TabNavigator.

Here is my code:

```
const MyTab = createBottomTabNavigator({
  FirstTabStack,
  SecondTabStack,
  ThirdTabStack,
  FourthTabStack,
});

class CustomNavigator extends React.Component {
  static router = MyTab.router;
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      {/* This SafeAreaView is from ReactNavigation. 
          forceInset-bottom-never is needed because  the 
          TabNavigator is already Safe-area-ing the bottom. 
          You don't want to do it again.*/}
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }}>
        {/* SearchHeader is zIndex: 1(or elevation: 1) for the absolute 
            positioned stuff that appears and cover the 
            screen after focusing on Input. */}
        <SearchHeader/>
        <MyTab navigation={navigation} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}


export default createDrawerNavigator({
  CustomNavigator,
  SettingsScreen,
  LegalScreen,
  FeedbackScreen,
  VersionScreen,
}, {
  drawerType: 'slide',
  drawerWidth: 260,
});
```

PS. If you want to have some overlaying absolute position-ed View covering where the TabNavigator is rendered, make sure to use **zIndex** for iOS, and **elevation** for Android!! In my case, SearchHeader component has:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        zIndex: 1,
      },
      android: {
        elevation: 1
      },
    }),
  },
  {...}
})
```

Answer (score 16):

The react native's component [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) has a property `ListHeaderComponent` for rendering a header and another one to stick it `stickyHeaderIndices`. This is exactly what you need.

In the `ListHeaderComponent` you will render your search field and with `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` will set it as a sticky header:

```
<FlatList
    data={ this.state.data }
    renderItem={({item}) =>  this.renderItem(item)}
    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
    stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
/>
```

Check out the working [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@hristoeftimov/fixed-searchfield).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for atm. I edited my question with an example screenshot! 

Comment: I see. Then you need to create a component and to import it on each screen ... (HOC is also a solution 

Comment: Thank you! Yup. I created a component and added to every screen like you said. It's just when the screen navigates, the animation is ugly, and the search input's value is not shared between screens (I can pass it around using props or any storage like redux though). Hmmm

Comment: i wish this example worked. I am in shock at how difficult react native makes it to make a fixed header.

Comment: @Starfs the snack works again! Thanks for reporting it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a component with `position: 'absolute'` style attribute (and a set `minHeight` - the height you want your search bar). Then you can import this in your root level component, and put a `marginTop: ...` style attribute on the rest of your app content (page container) equal to the `minHeight` you set for your header/search bar.

This way the header will display on all pages, and the rest of your app's content won't display behind the header.

You can find a basic example of this [here](https://snack.expo.io/@jonoh/sticky-header-example)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and let you kno what happend! I need to have that fixed header with the view created by 'createAppContainer' from ReactNavigation. I'll try!

Comment: DO NOT use position: absolute, because of [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27232), you will regret using this solution later.