# Flatlist horizontal inside Flatlist vertical with scroll

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

how are you guys?

I'm having a problem chaining lists

- I need to have a horizontal flatlist and for each item in that flalist I need to have another vertical flatlist
- horizontal flatlists need to independently scroll each content
- and hide the header as if it were an item in this list

```
const Content = () => 
    (
      <View>
        // when scrolling the flatlist Cat, I need to hide this header view
        <View 
          style={styles.container}
        >
          <Text>HEADER</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList //FlatList A
            data={CATEGORIES}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            snapToInterval={screenWidth}
            decelerationRate='fast'
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              // Cat FlatList
              <FlatList FlatList B
                  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                  data={getRandomData(item.cat)}
                  onEndReached={nextPage}
                  renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>}
                />
            )}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

Example iFood (or Twitter) App [here](https://gifyu.com/image/SEfMg) (click to play)
The header with address and categories moves along with the current list and remains fixed even when changing categories

I made a sketch [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@rafinhaa/358a02)

Notice that when you have a scrollview to go back from all the flatlists the scroll doesn't work, I would like to have a behavior similar to ifood, does anyone know how?

--edit
This [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbOdz.gif) exemplifies better, the lists scroll independently, but I would like to hide the header (View in gray color), when any of these lists scroll

Comment: It is not clear to me what exact effect you want to achieve. Not everyone uses iFood App (e.g. I don't), so just presenting a static screenshot of that app doesn't really help convey your vision. Maybe show a gif of the action you want.

Comment: Hello, please click on the image that the gif will load

Comment: Are you asking for the header to always remain or stick to the top as you scroll through the various flatlists? If so, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264425/is-there-a-fixed-header-or-sticky-header-for-react-native

Comment: it's very similar, but I need to hide the header while scrolling the B lists, I tried to use a scrollview outside the A flatlist, but that makes the B flatlists scroll together and not independently